# Circular Reference for Parent Link on Work Item cannot be resolved by Retry

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, opshub

I receive the following error:

> OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getCollectionMetaData. Server Error : TF201063: Adding a Parent link to work item 1737 would result in a circular relationship. To create this link, evaluate the existing links, and remove one of the other links in the cycle.

I have completely flattened out the Work Items in the source project. When retrying the migration the timestamp is modified on the pending errors however the issues are not resolved. These Work Items now have no parents or children in the source project. So I'm wondering if the retry list is no longer valid but there doesn't appear to be a away to have it update?

I can run the whole migration again, however it takes 5-7 hours to just do the work items so it would be great if there is a quick fix.

Comment: Please update the screenshot from the source work-item history, so that we could derive in which order the links were added on the source Team Foundation Server instance.
    This will enable us to generate scenario and suggest solution or fix it in our code.
Alternative solution or Work around:
An alternate is to once you receive this error, you can go to the target and delete the relationships on work-item for which this error is reported.
    Once done, just retry the failed events from Manage Failure(s) screen and start the migration again, it will now be able to add existing links.

Answer (score 3):

Was able to solve this problem by doing the following;

- Removing all links in the source for the work items with issues (recording this so it can be put back afterwards)
- Ran migration again
- Navigate to the task in question in the target. Notice that a new parent and child links were present (even though there should be none according to the source).
- Opened the parent link and removed the child link then saved.
- Then removed the child link in the parent.
- Marked all items for Retry and restarted the migration.

Last task, is now to put the links back in the target as they were originally in the source.

Comment: So you had to delete a whole bunch of data to get the migration to work? Did you have to add the links back afterwards?

Comment: "Whole bunch of data"... not sure if some links qualify as such? Obviously there were some issues with the original linkages but to answer your question, yes we removed the incorrect links, noted them down and then put the ones that made sense into the target.